# How To Circumvent 504 Errors

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-504, pdftables

I am working in ReactJs and one of the main aspects of our project is the ability to upload a scorecard and have all of its results parsed and placed into objects. However, due to the nature of these pdfs that get uploaded, there's a LOT of information, an average of 12-14 pages.
Most of the information is irrelevant, I usually will only need pages 5-7, but users will be users, and they upload all 12.
I am using the pdfParser API which is very good, we're not looking for replacements on that. However, due to how large the file is, if I am somewhere with only half-decent connection, I am hit with a 504 error since the process takes so long. If I have good to great connection, there's no issue.
This being said I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to extend the amount of time that needs to elapse before my computer gives up on the process
2. Is there a way to parse only SOME of the pages that get submitted?

The relevant code will be shown below...

```
var url = 'https://pdftables.com/api?key=770oukvvx1wl&format=xlsx-single';

const pdfToExcel = (pdfFile) => {
    var req = request.post({encoding: null, url: url}, async function (err, resp, body) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            fs.writeFile(`${pdfFile.path}.xlsx`, body, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error writing file');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('error retrieving URL');
        };
    });
    
    var form = req.form();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(`./${pdfFile.path}`));
}

const parseExcel = async (file) => {
    let workSheetsFromFile;

    if (file.path.search(".xlsx") === -1) {
        const filePath = await path.resolve(`./${file.path}.xlsx`)
        workSheetsFromFile = await xlsx.parse(`./${file.path}.xlsx`);
        await fs.unlinkSync(`./${file.path}`)
        await fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
        return workSheetsFromFile[0].data
    }
    
    if (file.path.search(".xlsx") !== -1) {
        const filePath = await path.resolve(`./${file.path}`)
        workSheetsFromFile = await xlsx.parse(`./${file.path}`);
        await fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
        return workSheetsFromFile[0].data
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to make the HTTP POST request? I suggest reading the docs for that library to see if it has a way to set the timeout length.

Comment: Also, you should make `pdfToExcel` async so that it doesn't interfere with any other processing.

Comment: ah yes that was perfect, I'm using Axios and I can manually set the timout for that. Thank you!